# Apache redirects sitemap.xml to error component

Tags: xml, apache, angular, .htaccess

Here is my Angular router config:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent,
data: {
  animation: {
    value: 'home',
  }
}
},
{ path: 'about',  component: AboutComponent,
data: {
  animation: {
    value: 'about',
  }
}
},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }
];
```

Each time I try to navigate to www.myapp.com/sitemap.xml it matches the ErrorComponent and redirects to my 404 page.

How can I configure the apache server to stop sitemap.xml going to index.html?

Below is my rewrite rule in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Configure your server **not** to serve index.html when the path is sitemap.xml

Comment: How can I target sitemap.xml in the .htaccess file?

Comment: I have added the .htaccess code to the post

Comment: You need to change the text of your question, and its tags, too. The actual question is about apache http server and .htaccess files, not about xml and angular.

Comment: Can you see what I am trying to do now?

Comment: I am the one who told you to configure the server not to serve index.html when the path is sitemap.xml. So yes, I know what you're trying to do. But I don't know shit about Apache and htaccess files, so I can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just needed to add the below rewrite rule to redirect to the sitemap.xml file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.xml [L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```